# LVM volume group is inactive after reboot of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

For no reason LVM volume group is inactive after every boot of OS. Manual activation works fine. Didn't touch any configs for several months.

I do not use RAID and OS is booting from usual partition.

The only thing I do regularly is:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade.
```

How can I force it to activate as it was a day ago?

My system details:

> Linux server 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
root@server:~# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               data
  PV Size               2.73 TiB / not usable 3.46 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              715396
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          715396
  PV UUID               Lcd805-EmRG-mk6o-eXgV-psP9-V6rp-7fGfde

root@server:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               data
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               2.73 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              715396
  Alloc PE / Size       715396 / 2.73 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               GlZi9o-8zQ2-Jnao-twAh-XjEE-mAEN-5EMOIf

root@server:~# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/data/web
  LV Name                web
  VG Name                data
  LV UUID                afnB4a-SCrl-XHDt-R1mb-flSc-Rto5-1CdaOJ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time server, 2014-12-26 23:56:51 +0300
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                2.00 TiB
  Current LE             524288
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/data/data
  LV Name                data
  VG Name                data
  LV UUID                KKo37f-qg2a-VBUt-3Qch-ULhC-YccS-Iaxwxz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time server, 2014-12-27 00:02:59 +0300
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                746.52 GiB
  Current LE             191108
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

Comment: Something wrong with the initramfs maybe. You may have an incomplete update, does `sudo dpkg --configure -a` do anything? Does `sudo update-initramfs -u` help?

Comment: No, dpkg --configure -a does nothing and update-initramfs -u doesn't help.
The workaround is to add "vgchange -ay" to /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2 and rebuild initramfs image, but I want to find the reason why it broke without any interference in any system configs.

Comment: `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2` is supposed to only activate the volume group containing the root filesystem. Other volume groups are supposed to be activated by an init script (or systemd, I think, since 16.04). It might be worth reporting this as a bug, with all the details of your configuration (in particular your LVM setup). Even here, please tell us what your LVM setup is: what groups you have and how you use them (what filesystems you mount, whether they're on RAID or encrypted volumes, etc.).

Comment: There is /etc/init.d/lvm2 script which is assigned to run level S, but it doesn't work.
Bug was reported 5 months ago: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1573982
I don't use LVM for root fs, raid and don't use encryption. Just single 3TB HDD which is used only for lvm group data with volumes data and web on it. Added info to initial question.